# Find all positive integers $n$ such that

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

$3^n+22^n$ is a perfect square.

Obviously $n=1$ is an answer but i'm not sure how to show that there aren't infinite solutions.

Comment: $n$ cannot be even, since $(22^{m})^2<22^{2m}+3^{2m} < (22^m+1)^2$.

Comment: $n$ cannot be odd if $n\geq 3$, since $3^n + 22^n = (-1)^n + 2^n = 3 \pmod 4$

Answer (score 3):

We can show $n$ cannot be even, since $(22^{m})^2<22^{2m}+3^{2m} < (22^m+1)^2$.

If $n$ is odd and $n>1$, then $3^n+22^n\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

So $n=1$ is the only solution.